# UIView Animation Not Animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a snippet of code which animates the position of a UIImage however the transition is not animated - instead the position just changes instantly. I do not believe it is a code issue as the same code works on another project but I am unable to figure out what else is wrong.

```
class CenterViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var logoView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var logoViewVerticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        animateLogo()
    }

    func animateLogo() {
        self.logoViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 35 - (self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
        logoView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
            self.logoView.alpha=1
            self.logoView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

The alpha animates but the y position does not. My constraints look like this

[image]

Specifically the one manipulated in the code is:
[image]

**Edit:** I am using Xcode-Beta 7 targeting 8.4

Comment: You should call `layoutIfNeeded` once before changing the constraints and once in the animation block, after the constraints are altered. Your code does work most of the time, but there are cases when you need to use this other approach, and yours might be one of them.

Comment: That doesn't have any effect and I'm not sure why it would

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
func animateLogo() {
    logoView.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
        self.logoViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 35 - (self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
        self.logoView.alpha=1
        self.logoView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: @clicky can you isolate the code for this view controller and upload it on github? So that it is possible to run and see why it is not working?

Comment: Don't forget to link the constraints on your storyboard.